# Razorpay ionic 3 callback issue

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I will implement razorpay with ionic 3 app everything works find, i got successcallback with payment_id but after that nothing happenig like redirect to other page or route or any other activity or calling functions etc.

I am refer following link,

https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova-sample-app/tree/master/rzp-ionic2-example

Here is my code,

```
var options = {
      description: 'Credits towards consultation',
      image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
      currency: 'INR',
      key: 'rzp_test_1DP5mmOlF5G5ag',
      amount: '5000',
      name: 'foo',
      prefill: {
        email: 'pranav@razorpay.com',
        contact: '8879524924',
        name: 'Pranav Gupta'
      },
      theme: {
        color: '#F37254'
      },
      modal: {
        ondismiss: function() {
          alert('dismissed')
        }
      }
    };

    var successCallback = function(payment_id) {
      alert('payment_id: ' + payment_id);
      this.navCtrl.push("ThankyouPage",{
              status: this.status
          });
    };

    var cancelCallback = function(error) {
      alert(error.description + ' (Error ' + error.code + ')');
    };

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      RazorpayCheckout.open(options, successCallback, cancelCallback);
    })
```

Comment: got RazorpayCheckout undefined error.can you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `arrow functions` like this:

```
var options = {
  description: 'Credits towards consultation',
  image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
  currency: 'INR',
  key: 'rzp_test_1DP5mmOlF5G5ag',
  amount: '5000',
  name: 'foo',
  prefill: {
    email: 'pranav@razorpay.com',
    contact: '8879524924',
    name: 'Pranav Gupta'
  },
  theme: {
    color: '#F37254'
  },
  modal: {
    ondismiss: () => { // <- Here!
      alert('dismissed')
    }
  }
};

var successCallback = (payment_id) => { // <- Here!
  alert('payment_id: ' + payment_id);
  this.navCtrl.push("ThankyouPage",{
          status: this.status
      });
};

var cancelCallback = (error) => { // <- Here!
  alert(error.description + ' (Error ' + error.code + ')');
};

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  RazorpayCheckout.open(options, successCallback, cancelCallback);
})
```

When using a regular function, the `this` keyword references the function itself, but when using arrow functions, **the `this` property is not overwritten and still references the component instance (where you defined the navCtrl property)**.

Comment: This does not work for me on the angular website, no issues in ionic mobile app

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this problem can be assigning this variable to some other variable and using it in the callback like -

```
let me = this;

var successCallback = function(payment_id) {
    alert('payment_id: ' + payment_id);
    me.navCtrl.push("ThankyouPage",{
        status: me.status
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it...

**step1:** let make one button with unique ID at html page

**step2:** `document.getElementById('your ID').click()`

What is a problem !!!

We are loading javascript function..there is no active method from javascript to typescript..so we should call html element to typescript..